# ggplot2: merge two legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to plot an area with two different set of points with ggplot2 but I get always two different legends. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148679/construct-a-manual-legend-for-a-complicated-plot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321163/ggplot2-merge-color-and-fill-legends)  but I still have two legends.
Below the code and the chart.
Thank you very much

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = letters,
                 y = 1:26 +runif(26),
                 z =  2*(1:26) +  runif(26),
                 jj = 1:26,
                 hh = 1:26*2,
                 x1 = 1:26)

some_names <- df %>% 
  filter(row_number() %% 10 == 1) %>% 
  select(x,x1)

p <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x1)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = y, ymax = z, fill = "area")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = jj, colour = "points1")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = hh, colour = "points2")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = some_names %>% select(x1) %>% unlist %>% unname,
                     labels =  some_names %>% select(x) %>% unlist %>% unname )

p + scale_fill_manual(name = "legend",
                      values = c("area" = "red","points1" = NA,"points2" = NA)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "legend",
                      values = c("area" = NA ,"points1" = "blue","points2" = "purple"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something in the veins of

```
library(tidyverse)
packageVersion("ggplot2")
# [1] ‘2.2.1’
df %>% 
  gather(var, val, jj, hh) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x1, val, ymin=y, ymax=z, color=var, fill=var)) + 
  geom_ribbon(color=NA) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","purple"), name="leg", labels = c("lab1","lab2")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = rep("red", 2), name="leg", labels= c("lab1","lab2"))
```

[image]

or

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  gather(var, val, jj, hh) %>% 
  bind_rows(data.frame(x=NA,y=NA,z=NA,x1=NA,var="_dummy",val=NA)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x1, val, ymin=y, ymax=z, color=var, fill=var)) + 
  geom_ribbon(color=NA) + 
  geom_ribbon(color=NA, fill="red") + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(
    values=c("#FFFFFF00", "blue","purple"), name="leg", labels = c("lab1","lab2","lab3")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("red", rep(NA, 2)), name="leg", labels= c("lab1","lab2","lab3"))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. I think we are close but the legend is still different from what I expected. There should be three element: the area (red) and the two set of points (lab1 blu e lab2 purple)

Comment: @LucaMonno This does not seem very ggplot'ish. Maybe hack your way through something like `df %>% 
  gather(var, val, jj, hh) %>% 
  bind_rows(data.frame(x=NA,y=NA,z=NA,x1=NA,var="_dummy",val=NA)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x1, val, ymin=y, ymax=z, color=var, fill=var)) + 
  geom_ribbon(color=NA) + 
  geom_ribbon(color=NA, fill="red") + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FFFFFF00", "blue","purple"), name="leg", labels = c("lab1","lab2","lab3")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", rep(NA, 2)), name="leg", labels= c("lab1","lab2","lab3")) `.

Comment: Thank you again. What do you meano for "not ggplot'ish": my dataset is not enough tidy for the plot or the plot I want itself is not ggplot'ish?

Comment: I meant the legend is not ggplot'ish (mixing fill with color aesthetics). Although I would have assumed that you could tweak it easily using guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=...))). However, for some reason that I don't understand, it does not work.

Comment: @LucaMonno Maybe you should delete the question and post it again with also a screenshot of the desired output, so that it's clear what the result should look like. (Older posts do not get that much attention and someone, who might have an idea, could have missed it.)

Comment: @LucaMonno Sure, just did so

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use an interior fill for each element. There may be a way to use `override.aes` to get the points to be a point in the legend, but I wasn't able to get that with any quick experimentation.

```
p <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x1)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = y, ymax = z, fill = "area")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = jj, fill = "points1"), shape=21, colour="blue") + 
  geom_point(aes(y = hh, fill = "points2"), shape=21, colour="purple") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = some_names %>% select(x1) %>% unlist %>% unname,
                     labels =  some_names %>% select(x) %>% unlist %>% unname ) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "legend",
                    values = c("area" = "red","points1" = "blue","points2" = "purple"),
                    guide = guide_legend(override.aes=aes(colour=NA)))

p
```

[image]