# removing part of a fill legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am facing a difficulty for a plot: I want to remove a part of a fill legend in a `ggplot` plot, while keeping the automated coloring. here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:20,y1 = rnorm(20,2,0.2),y2 = sqrt(1:20))
df2 <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,5,10),x2 = c(5,10,20),color2 = as.factor(1:3))

ggplot(data=df1) +
  geom_rect(data = df2,
            aes(xmin = x1,
                xmax = x2,
                ymin = 0,
                ymax = Inf,
                fill = color2),
            color = "black",
            size = 0.3,
            alpha = 0.2)+
  geom_bar(aes(x = x,
               y= y1,
               fill = "daily"),
           stat='identity',
           width = 0.75,
           size = 0.1,
           alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x,
                y =y2,
                color = "somthing"),
            size = 1.5)
```

[image]

I would like to:

- keep only the `daily` entry of the fill legend
- keep the automated filling based on the `color2` for the `geom_rect`
- ideally, merge the two legends (color and fill) into one

I have been playing around with `scale_fill_manual` and `guide`, but I did not come with something working. I feel that the solution could be making two independent layer and add them, but I don't know how to do that.

Does anyone know how to do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember you can set the `breaks` on any scale, so just set a single break at `"daily"` on your fill scale. To merge it with the color scale (if I understand your meaning) you can just give the color guide and its single break the same names as the fill guide and fill break:

```r
ggplot(data=df1) +
  geom_rect(data = df2,
            aes(xmin = x1,
                xmax = x2,
                ymin = 0,
                ymax = Inf,
                fill = color2),
            color = "black",
            size = 0.3,
            alpha = 0.2)+
  geom_bar(aes(x = x,
               y= y1,
               fill = "daily"),
           stat='identity',
           width = 0.75,
           size = 0.1,
           alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x,
                y =y2,
                color = "somthing"),
            size = 1.5) +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = "daily", name = NULL) +
   scale_color_discrete(name = "labels") +
  theme(legend.margin = margin(0, 0, -10, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: it looks good ! A further question: If I want now to set manually the colour of the fill of `geom_rect`, with for example `viridis` scale ? is it possible ?

Comment: Yes @denis. You can choose `scale_fill_manual` and put whatever colours you like in `values` while keeping the single break, or use `scale_fill_viridis_d`

Comment: Almost perfect! I still do not manage to merge the legends, as you changed the legend of my line from `"somthing"` to `"daily"` . If the legend are differents, the two legends are separated with your example

Comment: @denis that's right. If they are called two different things how can they be labelled in the legend?

Comment: I would like the line with "something" and the color with daily under the same "label" legend. With your example, I get two legend with the title "label", one for color, one for fill.

Comment: @denis that's just some theme tweaking  - see my update

Comment: whaou ! I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321163/ggplot2-merge-color-and-fill-legends) and came up with something so more complicated! I would not have thing of the theme change. bravo!